# using shell script: file name date string compare with current date

Tags: shell, unix

Hi Unix and Shell script experts,
I want a script.
Every friday (`20220909` for example) I am getting three file

```
20220909_abc.txt
20220910_abc.txt
20220911_abc.txt
```

with shell script I need to check this three files, get the `YYYYMMDD` part, and need to cross check with latest dates (today /tomorrow/next day), if they match continue else fail

```
20220910_abc.txt--->20220910-->next day..i.e 20220910 (which current date+1)

20220911_abc.txt--->20220911-->next day..i.e 20220911 (which current date+2)
```

If we got any file out of range (like older than `20220909` or greater than `20220911`), need to fail. Appreciate you provide some insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really spend much time but assuming you are trying to compare the dates with filenames like `20220910_abc.txt`

you can use the following snippet

```bash
# get the latest date
latest_date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
echo "latest date is $latest_date"

# get the next day date
tomorrow=$(date -v+1d +%Y%m%d)
echo "tomorrow day is $tomorrow"

# get the next day date
day_after_tomorrow=$(date -v+2d +%Y%m%d)
echo "day after tomorrow day is $day_after_tomorrow"

# get the file name
file_name="20220913_abc.txt"
echo "file name is $file_name"

# get the file date
file_date=$(echo $file_name | cut -d'_' -f1)
echo "file date is $file_date"

# check if the file date is equal to latest date
if [ $file_date -eq $latest_date ]
then
    echo "file date is equal to latest date"
else
    echo "file date is not equal to latest date"
fi

# check if the file date is equal to tomorrow date
if [ $file_date -eq $tomorrow ]
then
    echo "file date is equal to tomorrow date"
else
    echo "file date is not equal to tomorrow date"
fi

# check if the file date is equal to day after tomorrow date
if [ $file_date -eq $day_after_tomorrow ]
then
    echo "file date is equal to day after tomorrow date"
else
    echo "file date is not equal to day after tomorrow date"
fi
```

Running

```bash
╰─ bash test.sh
latest date is 20220911
tomorrow day is 20220912
day after tomorrow day is 20220913
file name is 20220913_abc.txt
file date is 20220913
file date is not equal to latest date
file date is not equal to tomorrow date
file date is equal to day after tomorrow date
```

Comment: Thank you , appreciate it .. is there any way ..we can pass this in array1 ,which got all file names  ,array2 have all 3 days will ,and in a single shot can we compare ?

Comment: Every friday : we will get three files in a directory ..we need loop all name of files into a array1 ..and need loop 3 latest days into another array2 ..and compare array1 with array2 in a single shot.

Comment: you can use a `for` loop or `while` for the same. Please do accept the answer this helps.

Comment: I would not use an array when you only create the array for the single shot. I would implement a function `check_file_date()` taking a filename as an argument. Next use 3 calls: `check_file_date 20220909_abc.txt`, `check_file_date 
20220910_abc.txt` and `20220911_abc.txt`. You can change the function to take 3 (or any number) of arguments or an array, but for 3 files I would prefer calling a function 3 times.